# Неправильно работает readline, считывает всего одну строку

Tags: python, файловый-ввод-вывод

Код:

```
b = open('GG.txt')
B = b.readline()
print(B)
```

Файл GG.txt:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Выводит только 1 и заканчивает работу без ошибки
Что делать ?

Comment: все правильно `file.readline()` - читает одну строку, а `file.readlines()` - читает все строки и возвращает список строк

Answer (score 1):

Как правильно заметил [MaxU](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/211923/maxu) [в комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1170337/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-readline-%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%83-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83#comment2032841_1170337), ваша ошибка в том, что `file.readline()` и `file.readlines()` - это разные методы. Первый считывает последовательно по одной строке, второй - все строки в виде списка разом.

Если у вас есть файл `GG.txt`:

```
1
2
3
4
```

то вывод этих методов будет следующим:

```py
b = open('GG.txt')
B = b.readline()  # <== считывание одной строки
print(B)          # вернет "1\n"

# ---------------------------------------

B = b.readlines()  # <== считывание всех строк
print(B)          # вернет ["1\n", "2\n", "3\n", "4\n"]
```

Comment: Тогда как можно вывести не в виде списка, а на разных строках ?

Comment: `print(''.join(B))` - это "склеивание" элементов списка через разделитель (здесь разделитель - пустая строка, так как у вас переносы строк уже есть в элементах). Если переносов строк нет в элементах, то так: `print('\n'.join(B))`

Comment: Так же можно простым циклом по списку и поэлементно выводить.